# Installing psiphon on Debian 10 gives make: *** [Makefile:129: authfd.o] Error 1

Tags: debian, networking, make, proxy, configure

I am trying to install psiphon on Debian 10 based on instructions here
https://github.com/thispc/psiphon
then ./configure came across error

```
configure: error: *** zlib.h missing - please install first or check
config.log ***
```

https://pastebin.com/ANGa0c7q
to get rid of above error I did

```
sudo apt-get install libz-dev
```

Then I did ./configure and found a new error

```
configure: error: *** OpenSSL headers missing
```

full message can be seen here
https://pastebin.com/9XFUYZkk
I then tried doing

```
debian@debian:~/psiphon/openssh-5.9p1$ sudo apt-get install openssl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
openssl is already the newest version (1.1.1c-1).
openssl set to manually installed.
```

Then I did   install libssl-dev
doing a ./configure needed an openssl and

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

I got following

```
configure: error: Your OpenSSL headers do not match your
library. Check config.log for details.
If you are sure your installation is consistent, you can disable the check
by running "./configure --without-openssl-header-check".
Full message here https://pastebin.com/pyHiyG3j
```

I  executed `./configure --without-openssl-header-check`
full messages https://pastebin.com/UsEZcgKi
now as the instructions here say https://github.com/thispc/psiphon
to do a make after

```
./configure
```

I get a following message

```
authfd.c: In function ‘ssh_encode_identity_ssh2’:
authfd.c:499:33: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘DSA’
{aka ‘struct dsa_st’}
   buffer_put_bignum2(b, key->dsa->p);
                                 ^~
make: *** [Makefile:129: authfd.o] Error 1
```

full message of make https://pastebin.com/0eSzXLxm
what should I do now how to proceed from here.
I am on Debian 10. 
All error message at one place https://pastebin.com/CuMRuExj

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get remove libssl-dev
apt-get install libssl1.0-dev 
make
```